# Laravel Restful Resource Controller routing getShow()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having difficulty getting the Restful routes defined here ([Laravel Documentation: Restful Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)) to work properly.

I can get the create form and the index (view of all) to work properly but I cannot get the link to a single item to work properly. The getShow

I have defined my route as restful so it should use the automatic routing in my routes.php:

```
// People
Route::controller('people', 'PeopleController');
```

Here is my controller PeopleController.php:

```
<?php
class PeopleController extends BaseController {

    public $restful = true;

    public function getIndex()
    {   


        return View::make('people.index')
            ->with('people', $people);          
    }

    public function getShow($id)
    {   
    return 'success! it finally worked!';   
    }


    public function getCreate()
    {
        return View::make('people.create');
    }

    public function postStore()
    {

            return Redirect::to('people')
                ->with('success', 'Person added successfully');
     }

}
```

Here is my index.blade.php template which should link to the show.blade.php template:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    @foreach ($people as $people)
    <li> <a href="{{ URL::to('people/' . $people->people_id) }}" class="thumbnail"> <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s200x200/486010_633561579994787_1827482783_n.jpg" /> </a>
        <div class="caption">

            <p> {{ $people->people_id }}<br />
            {{ $people->firstname }}<br />
                {{ $people->lastname }}<br />
                {{ $people->line1 }}<br />
                {{ $people->city }}<br />
                <br />
                {{ $people->state }} {{ $people->zip }}<br />
                {{ $people->country }} </p>
            <p>
                <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="button">Actions</button>
                <button class="btn btn-small" type="button">View</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

I have a view created called show.blade.php.

```
@extends('master')

@section('title')
@parent
:: Home
@stop

@section('content')
<p>it finally worked!</p>

@stop
```

But whenever I go to an item such as people/1 I get a crap ton of errors:.

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller.php290
Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller missingMethod
<#unknown>0
call_user_func_array
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller.php138
Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller callMethod
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller.php115
Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller callAction
…\bootstrap\compiled.php9980
Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
<#unknown>0
call_user_func_array
…\bootstrap\compiled.php16626
Illuminate\Routing\Route callCallable
…\bootstrap\compiled.php16605
Illuminate\Routing\Route run
…\bootstrap\compiled.php10000
Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatch
…\bootstrap\compiled.php1010
Illuminate\Foundation\Application dispatch
…\bootstrap\compiled.php993
Illuminate\Foundation\Application run
…\public\index.php49
```

At this point I've stripped my code down to the bare bones just to get this to work. I'm finding that perhaps the RESTful features are not so helpful since the documentation is so lacking. Is there anyway to get to the OLD version 3 documentation?

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate it. It seems to be correct as per the docs but it does not detail at all how this works. :( As a newcomer to Laravel I'm not sure if I'm just missing something, or if the docs really don't elaborate what needs to be done.

Would it be better to just create my own routes instead of trying to use the built in functions? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try people/show/1 because there isn't an argument in the getIndex method declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your links to....

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('people/show/' . $people->people_id) }}">
```

So as to trigger the getShow() method, which will accept your argument of $id.

The way you have it now, its going to people/1 which is just bringing up getIndex(), which doesn't accept any arguments, hence your error.

If you do want people/1 to do something then you would change your getIndex() function to something like this.....

```
function getIndex($id=null){
    if($id==null){
       $people = People::all();           
     } else {
       $people = People::find($id);
     }
    return View::make('people.index')
    ->with('people', $people);  
  }
```

But I doubt thats what you want

I bet just changing the link, as I mentioned above, will fix your problem :)

Comment: I'd use `{{ url('people/show', $people->people_id) }}`, you can pass the parameters to the function without string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use resource routing: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers
The controllers are RESTful, and easier to understand. The only place I use controller routing is for controllers that handle arbitrary items, like a PagesController. This way you have a consistent way of accessing your pages.